# how to print all post results when a form is submitted

Tags: php

What is wrong with this code??  It doesn't echo the answer.

```
<?php
     $num1=$_POST['fnum'];
     $num2=$_POST['snum'];

     $sum=$num1 + $num2;
     $diff=$num1 - $num2;
     $prod=$num1 * $num2;
     $quo=$num1 / $num2;
     $mod=$num1 % $num2;


     echo "The sum is " .$sum. <br>;
     echo "The differense is " .$diff. <br>;
     echo "The product is " .$prod. <br>;
     echo "The quotient is " .number_format($quo,2). <br>;
     echo "The remainder is " .$mod. <br>;
  ?>
```

Comment: Use print_r($_POST) to look into every subitted value. Though the answer is badly asked. At least try to use correct english.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating the `<br>` tag in wrong way.

```
echo "The sum is " .$sum. <br>;
```

It should be:

```
echo "The sum is " .$sum. "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numbers `10` and `5` taken from a form using a POST method:

Gave the following results: (from the fixed version found below)

> The sum is 15
>   The differense is 5
>   The product is 50
>   The quotient is 2.00
>   The remainder is 0

You were missing quotes for the concatenates.

I.e.:

```
echo "The sum is " .$sum.  <br> ;
             missing "    ^    ^
```

and the others as well.

This works with no parse errors:

```
<?php
     $num1=$_POST['fnum'];
     $num2=$_POST['snum'];

     $sum=$num1 + $num2;
     $diff=$num1 - $num2;
     $prod=$num1 * $num2;
     $quo=$num1 / $num2;
     $mod=$num1 % $num2;

     echo "The sum is " .$sum. "<br>";
     echo "The differense is " .$diff. "<br>";
     echo "The product is " .$prod. "<br>";
     echo "The quotient is " .number_format($quo,2). "<br>";
     echo "The remainder is " .$mod. "<br>";
?>
```

---

It could also be done like this, giving the same output format:

```
<?php
     $num1=$_POST['fnum'];
     $num2=$_POST['snum'];

     $sum=$num1 + $num2;
     $diff=$num1 - $num2;
     $prod=$num1 * $num2;
     $quo=$num1 / $num2;
     $mod=$num1 % $num2;

     echo "The sum is " .$sum;
     echo "<br>";
     echo "The differense is " .$diff;
     echo "<br>";
     echo "The product is " .$prod;
     echo "<br>";
     echo "The quotient is " .number_format($quo,2);
     echo "<br>";
     echo "The remainder is " .$mod;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good if we could see the code you're using to post to the PHP. From a quick scan of what you've put, it seems that may be your issue. Make sure you're posting with the names fnum and snum in a way that you can then use in calculations. I'd suggest wrapping the inputs as follows:

```
$num1 = floatval($_POST['fnum']);
$num2 = floatval($_POST['snum']);
```

That'll ensure whatever you're pulling in is a number.